# I want to see first page in my canvas. How can i make it?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pypdf

```
import PyPDF4
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import io

class PDF_Region_Selector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pdf_file = None
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.browse_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Browse", command=self.browse_file)
        self.browse_button.pack()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=600, height=800)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.finish_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Finish", command=self.finish_selecting)
        self.finish_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        self.clear_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Clear", command=self.clear_regions)
        self.clear_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

        self.regions = []

        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

        self.root.mainloop()
    def browse_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("PDF Files", "*.pdf")])

        if file_path:
            self.pdf_file = open(file_path, 'rb')
            self.pdf_reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(self.pdf_file)

            self.page = self.pdf_reader.getPage(0)
            self.page_width = float(self.page.mediaBox.getWidth())
            self.page_height = float(self.page.mediaBox.getHeight())
            self.canvas.config(width=self.page_width, height=self.page_height)

            self.image = self.page_to_image(self.page)
            self.image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
            self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.image_tk)

    def page_to_image(self, page):
        x, y, w, h = page.mediaBox
        image = Image.new('RGB', (int(w), int(h)), (255, 255, 255))
        image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        page.writeToStream(image_stream)
        image_stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(image_stream)
        return image

    def clear_regions(self):
        self.canvas.delete("region")
        self.regions = []

    def on_click(self, event):
        self.start_x, self.start_y = event.x, event.y

    def on_release(self, event):
        end_x, end_y = event.x, event.y

        rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            self.start_x, self.start_y, end_x, end_y,
            outline='red', width=2, tags="region"
        )
        self.canvas.tag_lower(rect)

        region = {
            'x1': self.start_x,
            'y1': self.start_y,
            'x2': end_x,
            'y2': end_y,
            'text': ""
        }
        self.regions.append(region)

        self.open_text_entry(region)

    def open_text_entry(self, region):
        top = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        top.title("Enter Text")
        top.geometry("300x100")

        text_label = tk.Label(top, text="Enter text:")
        text_label.pack()

        text_entry = tk.Entry(top)
        text_entry.pack()

        submit_button = tk.Button(top, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.save_text(region, text_entry.get(), top))
        submit_button.pack()

    def save_text(self, region, text, top):
        region['text'] = text
        top.destroy()

    def finish_selecting(self):
        self.pdf_file.close()
        self.root.destroy()

        for i, region in enumerate(self.regions):
            x1, y1, x2, y2, text = region['x1'], region['y1'], region['x2'], region['y2'], region['text']
            print(f"Region {i + 1}: (x1={x1}, y1={y1}), (x2={x2}, y2={y2}), Text: {text}")

PDF_Region_Selector()
```

Please give me advice how to make new method for this

I tried to use MyPDF or PyPDF2, but it gived me many errors((

Comment: Your code will raise exception on the line `page.writeToStream(image_stream)`.  `PyPDF4` is not a proper module in your case, try using `PyMuPDF` instead.